# matplotlib one centered axis label for two diagrams

Tags: matplotlib, label, axis

I'd like to have one axis label centered over two axes in matplotlib.

For example, I set up the axes as follows:

```
figure     = pyplot.figure(figsize=10,10))
diagram1   = figure.add_axes([0.01,0.62,0.90,0.30])
diagram2   = figure.add_axes([0.01,0.32,0.90,0.30])
```

This will generate two diagrams on top of each other. How can i now define one axis label for the y axis centered on both diagrams.

I think this can be done with subplots, but I prefer to set every diagram individually, as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually change the y-coordinate of the label.

```
diagram1.set_ylabel('y label').set_y(0)
# Alternatively you can use
# diagram2.set_ylabel('y label').set_y(1)
```

The coordinate is in the [axes coordinate](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html#axes-coordinates) space, meaning 0 is the bottom and 1 is the top of the `Axes`.

Seeing how your `Axes` are placed at x=0.01, you can make the label appear at the right side of the plots as well

```
diagram1.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
```